# Taylor series $x\ln(2+x)$ about $0$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am trying to obtain Taylor serie from  $x\ln(2+x)$ about $0$, but somehow i dont get right solution which is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{(n+1)}x^{n+1}}{n2^{n}}$$

here are derivates i get : 
$$f'(x) =\ln(2+x) + \left.\dfrac{x}{(2+x)} \right.$$
$$f''(x) = \left.\dfrac{1}{(2+x)} \right.+\left.\dfrac{2}{(2+x)^2} \right. $$
$$f'''(x) = -\left.\dfrac{1}{(2+x)^2} \right.-\left.\dfrac{4}{(2+x)^3} \right. $$
$$f''''(x) = \left.\dfrac{2}{(2+x)^3} \right.+\left.\dfrac{12}{(2+x)^4} \right. $$

i tried with $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\cdot x^k$$
but couldnt get right result.

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BD%5Bx*Log%5B2%2Bx%5D,%7Bx,n%7D%5D,%7Bn,1,5%7D%5D) may help you find the mistake.

Comment: Your given solution is most certainly wrong.  The coefficient of $x^1$ is most certainly $\ln(2)$

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: The given solution is wrong.

---

It's easier to consider simpler functions than directly taking derivatives.  For starters:

$$g(x)=\ln(1+x)\\g'(x)=\frac1{1+x}\\g''(x)=-\frac1{(1+x)^2}\\g'''(x)=\frac2{(1+x)^3}\\\vdots\\g^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^{k+1}\frac{(k-1)!}{(1+x)^k}\\g(0)=0\\g^{(k)}(0)=(-1)^{k+1}(k-1)!$$

Plugging this all in, we get

$$g(x)=g(0)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(k-1)!}{k!}x^k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}kx^k$$

> $$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}kx^k\tag1$$

Now let $x\mapsto x/2$ to get

$$\ln\left(1+\frac x2\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k2^k}x^k$$

Add $\ln(2)$ to both sides:

$$\begin{align}\ln\left(1+\frac x2\right)+\ln(2)&=\ln(2+x)\\&=\ln(2)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k2^k}x^k\end{align}$$

Finally, multiply both sides by $x$ to finish:

> $$x\ln(2+x)=x\ln(2)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k2^k}x^{k+1}\tag2$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\ln(2+x)=\ln(2)+\ln(1+x/2) $$

$$=\ln (2)+\frac {x}{2}-\frac {x^2}{8}+.. $$

Answer (score 0):

For $|x|<1$ we have $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{(n+1)}x^{n}}{n}$

Your turn !

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the formula with derivatives to compute a Taylor series! Do you really want to compute an infinite number of derivatives?

Use the fact that for $|x| < 1$, $$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \dfrac{x^n}{n}$$

Then $$x \ln(2+x)=x \ln(2(1+x/2))=x \ln(2) + x\ln(1+x/2) = x \ln(2) + x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \dfrac{x^n}{n2^n}$$